# .NET integratable robust, fast solution for surface reconstruction from 3D point cloud

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d-reconstruction

We have a .NET 4.0 C# WPF, machining simulation application. Right now we are stuck since we have to generate a 3D surface (mesh generation) from a point cloud. We have been searching, goggling, testing different libraries in order to find a solution that is fast, robust, correct and that can be integrated to our application but we had no luck. 3D imaging is not our line of business so we don't want to get into coding this part. A commercial solution with an affordable price can also be an answer for us.

Until now we have tried:

1. [VCGLib](http://vcg.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page) through MeshLab UI but the algorithm they use (Ball Pivoting) didn't give a good result.
2. A MatLab code based on PowerCrust algorithm ([MyCrust Robust](http://www.advancedmcode.org/surface-recostruction-from-scattered-points-cloud-mycrust-robust.html)) and it gave a good result but we don't think that if we recode this code in C#, it will gave us the performance that we want. We need a solution that can be easily integrated to our project.
3. While searching we have also came up with these [sample applications](http://www.den.rcast.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yu-ohtake/software/index.html). We don't know the detail of the algorithm used in these applications (details are in an academic paper) but it generated a result with so many missing meshes. But may be it can help to someone else.

Right now we are trying to learn [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) and find out whether it can be an answer for us. But since installing Boost and compiling CGAL took two days for us we just started on working on it.

Can anybody offer us a solution that can be in help to us?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi i am currently facing same problem........have you getting any solution? hope yes!!!! then please help me...... Thanks.....

Comment: No, unfortunately we're stuck :(

Comment: which algorithm you are planing to use?  i mean PowerCrust http://www.advancedmcode.org/surface-recostruction-from-scattered-points-cloud-mycrust-robust.html, Marching cube   http://www.exaflop.org/docs/marchcubes/, Poisson  http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.5/doc_html/cgal_manual/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/Chapter_main.html  which will be best etc.........  Thanks for replying........

Comment: i think we have to use POISSON SURFACE RECONSTRUCTION algorithm which is available with source code at here http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/ but the huge problem is it is in C++......so i have to reverse-engineer it and implement it in C#............ ARE YOU READY? THANKS.......for your consideration.......

Comment: If you don't need a real time solution you can use the line command of the Poisson algorithm

Comment: Hello. Now I have exactly the same problem. Did you manage to find any solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting mu data from the kinect depth map and I found these papers:

- http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/papers/zipper/zipper.pdf
- http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/papers/volrange/volrange.pdf

They might be helpful if you have the Poisson algorithm in C# it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is the G# library at http://www.ceometric.com
It can do a surface reconstruction from triangular or quadrilateral wireframe data. This is not exactly what you have been looking for but it may be a first step towards a solution.